# MAMP PRO: Access virtual host via different PC/device

Tags: networking, mamp, virtualhost

I'm new to the idea of Virtual hosts, but I have successfully used MAMP PRO to set one up on my Macbook Pro.

When I set the IP/Port option of the Virtual Host in the MAMP PRO interface, I am able to access it by typing that same IP into any device within my Internet connection. However, on devices other than my own Mac, none of the media shows. Just the bare HTML.

I am assuming this is because the device can't access the files on my Mac. The directory for the virtual host is setup in a folder on a separate partition. I'm not sure if storing it on OSX's partition or not makes a difference (I can change where it is stored if necessary).

How can I go about getting this to work?

Answer (score 0):

You don't give a lot of details to help you.

Haven't you forget to click on "Put Online"

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IP addresses to access the box, are you sure you are using virtual hosts? I'm assuming in that case you are using a IP/port combination?

Where is your media located - I'm assuming its *not* on port 80, and this is a host on a different port?

The files/permission/partition should be fine, since you are able to access it from your local host.

I suspect that what is happening - given that you are doing virtual hosts with the same IP address and different port - is that your Mac's firewall is blocking access to the port. Do you have your media files set up to be served from a port other than port 80 (or the one you are serving your HTML files from?) In that case, just open up the port on the firewall and it should work..

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the permissions of your media folder? Make sure the folder containing your media and its content have read privilege for "everyone". If the bare HTML show up (assuming it's in the same folder as your medias), it's not a connection problem.

You could also check if the media file give you an error 4xx or a 5xx error when you open the page on another computer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to test it out, there might be many reasons for it.

First, try to open CSS/Javascript files separately on another machine, if it's ok, then that's not your problem.

Second try to install View Dependencies Firefox extension and browse with that.

And last, check your firewall config. Apache won't filter contents on its ow.

Answer (score 0):

If you reach the HTML without media, styles, javascripts it's because you need to replace the path for them. You could have paths like `http://localhost/images/image.jpg` that make sense on the local machine but that are unreacheable from another machine over the network. You could ned to replace `localhost` with the server ip address.